# Second menu not showing

Tags: theme-development, menus

I am running WP 3.2.1 on a dedicated server and having a little trouble with a second menu.

I have a menu at the top of the page which is working fine but I've added a secondary left menu to the left column which is currently showing the top menu despite it being selected in the admin to show the left menu.

In my functions.php I have:

```
register_nav_menu( 'left-menu', __( 'Left Menu', 'rsi' ) );
register_nav_menu( 'top-menu', __( 'Top Menu', 'rsi' ) );
```

Then in my theme files I've called them up using:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array('rsi' => 'left-menu' ));?>
<?php wp_nav_menu( array('rsi' => 'top-menu' ));?>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass an array of menus to the `register_nav_menu` function like so:

```
register_nav_menus(
    array(
        'menu-1' => 'Menu Top',
        'menu-2' => 'Menu Bottom'
    )
);
```

You then call them in your theme:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'menu-2' ) ); ?>
```